# Trying to make a search bar to a data grid view and getting a SQLException

Tags: visual-studio, datagridview, sqlexception, inventory, searchbar

I'm trying to create a form with a data grid view, a combo box with columns, and a text box search bar. I've found lots of YouTube videos on line (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaQs1K63Q-o&list=PL4Io1EUy0d2zUOyEiVt-GwI6WzqdEgVbZ&index=15) and I keep getting an exception error. I've tried to look on the manuals, stack overflow forums, videos, and other sources for days and still coming up dry. I am very new to C# and programming SQL to C# so I think its something simple that I'm just not seeing. When I look closer in the exception detail it says that there is an error being returned by SQL Server. I've tried hitting it at all angles but nothing gets fixed.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = LAPTOP -                  2H9706D7\\THIBEAUX; Initial Catalog = MetroTest; Integrated Security = True");
```

This is the connection but this part is "2H97067\THIBEAUX; I put an extra "\" to get rid of the escape sequence error.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text == "ID")
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [Program Tools] where ID like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);//right here the exception is being thrown
            ToolDataGrid.DataSource = data;
        }

    }
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

can anyone help me out with this?

And yes I know I shouldn't have put spaces between my Tables names I'm working on renaming them later.

Comment: its not able to connect to server. How did you specify connection string .. See complete example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: See I thought that this was the connection string:

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = LAPTOP -                  2H9706D7\\THIBEAUX; Initial Catalog = MetroTest; Integrated Security = True");

Comment: Now if I go to app.cofig and select the <add name = "Metro_app1.Properties.Settings.MetroTestConnectionString">                            I've seen it done like this before. I'm sorry if I'm getting stuff wrong here I'm really new to sql and C# programming.                                               string connectionString = "Metro_app1.Properties.Settings.MetroTestConnectionString";

Comment: Can you try this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0qy7_l7vFg

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, took me a few tries but I got it!